# How to check for null in Twig?

Tags: php, twig, short-circuiting

What construct should I use to check whether a value is NULL in a Twig template?

Answer (score 563, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you need:

- [`is null`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/tests/null.html) checks whether the value is `null`:

```php
{% if var is null %}
    {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

- [`is defined`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/tests/defined.html) checks whether the variable is defined:

```php
{% if var is not defined %}
    {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

Additionally the [`is sameas`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/tests/sameas.html) test, which does a type strict comparison of two values, might be of interest for checking values other than `null` (like `false`):

```php
{% if var is sameas(false) %}
    {# do something %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And to check if something is not null, simply do `{% if var is not null %}`

Comment: quick note that: $var == null will return true with $var is 0, but $var is null will return false

Comment: Also note that $var == 0 will return true if $var is null

Comment: In addition, unlike the PHP `isset()` function, `is defined` will return `true` if a variable is defined and it's value is null.

Comment: Notice: as Twig 2.x check for variable is equal to value like `is_ sameas` must be `{% if var is same as(false) %}` not `{% if var is sameas(false) %}` see Doc url => https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html

Comment: To check if it's empty {% if var is empty %}{% endif %}

Answer (score 140):

How to set default values in twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

```
{{ my_var | default("my_var doesn't exist") }}
```

Or if you don't want it to display when null:

```
{{ my_var | default("") }}
```

Comment: So does it differentiate between `undefined or empty` and `null`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. 
Had to make sure that you have | default which you can then try defaulting to another variable like so: 
{{ my_var | default(my_var2) }}
I just tested, but you can even continue to chain like so:
{{ my_var | default(my_var2) | default("my_var and my_var2 do not exist") }}

Answer (score 39):

Without any assumptions the answer is:

```
{% if var is null %}
```

But this will be true only if `var` is exactly `NULL`, and not any other value that evaluates to `false` (such as zero, empty string and empty array). Besides, it will cause an error if `var` is not defined. A safer way would be:

```
{% if var is not defined or var is null %}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
{% if var|default is null %}
```

If you don't provide an argument to the `default` filter, it assumes `NULL` (sort of default default). So the shortest and safest way (I know) to check whether a variable is empty (null, false, empty string/array, etc):

```
{% if var|default is empty %}
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can. This is because if a variable is undefined (not set) in the twig template, it looks like `NULL` or `none` (in twig terms). I'm pretty sure this is to suppress bad access errors from occurring in the template.

Due to the lack of a "identity" in Twig (`===`) this is the best you can do

```
{% if var == null %}
    stuff in here
{% endif %}
```

Which translates to:

```
if ((isset($context['somethingnull']) ? $context['somethingnull'] : null) == null)
{
  echo "stuff in here";
}
```

Which if your good at your [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), means that things such as `0`, `''`, `FALSE`, `NULL`, and an undefined var will also make that statement true.

My suggest is to ask for the identity to be implemented into Twig.

Comment: Kendall is right to suggest that they implement it - I've had nothing but good experiences asking for things to be implemented on Twig's github issue tracker. They're very friendly and professional.

Comment: @kendall-hopkins Got curious, when is it appropriate to use `{if var is none}` and what is the PHP equivalent?

Comment: @noisebleed `{% if abcxyz is none %}` becomes `if (isset($context["abcxyz"])) { $_abcxyz_ = $context["abcxyz"]; } else { $_abcxyz_ = null; }`
`if ((null === $_abcxyz_)) { echo "hi"; }`. So basically if the value is undefined or null, it will be true.

Comment: @noisebleed Also `none` is an alias for `null` [ref](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/null.html).

Comment: The equivalent to this answer would also be to use `{% if var is empty %}` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html which translates to PHP `if (empty($var))` that evaluates against a falsey value (`!isset, null, 0, array(), "", false, "0", 0.0` ) http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php You can also use `{% if var is same as(var) %}` for identity (`===`). http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html

Answer (score 6):

You can also use one line to do that:

```
{{ yourVariable is not defined ? "Not Assigned" : "Assigned" }}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
     //test if varibale exist
     {% if var is defined %}
         //todo
     {% endif %}

     //test if variable is not null
     {% if var is not null %}
         //todo
     {% endif %}
```

Comment: Why do you think this answer is better than the currently accepted one?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the difference from already accepted answer? Is it outdated? Why your answer is better than already existing ones?

Comment: @STTLCU He's including `if var is not null`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following code to check whether

```
{% if var is defined %}

var is variable is SET

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if your variable is an **ARRAY**, there are few options too:

```
{% if arrayVariable[0] is defined %} 
    #if variable is not null#
{% endif %}
```

OR

```
{% if arrayVariable|length > 0 %} 
    #if variable is not null# 
{% endif %}
```

This will only works if your array `is defined` AND is `NULL`