# Check if a Entity Field Type returns a value in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a [Entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) in a form, how do I check in Twig if its returning any value?

The entity field type:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
    },
));
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: [How to check for null in Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig)

Comment: I was already trying that, the problem is that I dont know the name of  the variable...

Comment: You can see name of variable in controller when creating response or debugging all variables in action.

Comment: Looking to what I set in the controller, the name would be **form.users**, but already tried with no success :/

Comment: @jonfer, if you don't the variable name, you can still loop over your result and then check for empty value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct variable to check was: `form.users.vars.choices`

So the code would be:

```
{% if form.users.vars.choices|length > 0 %}     
   {# actions #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% if users.options|length > 0 %}
   {% for option in users.options %}                    
      {# some action #}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Gives me error: Variable "users" does not exist. I was already trying with |length > 0, the problem is that I dont know the name of variable.

Comment: `form.users` gives no error, but looks like the |length is always 0

Comment: Which simply means that your query did not find any users.  form.users itself is basically just an array and will always be set.

Comment: The query did find users cause the select is populated with the users. I dont know why the length stays 0...