# In Twig, check if a specific key of an array exists

Tags: php, arrays, twig, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

In PHP we can check if a key exists in an array by using the function `array_key_exists()`.

In the Twig templating language we can check if an variable or an object's property exists simply by using an `if` statement, like this:

```
{% if app.user %}
do something here
{% else %}
do something else
{% endif %}
```

But how do we check if a key of an *array* exists using Twig? I tried `{% if array.key %}`, but it gives me an error:

```
Key "key" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3...648" does not exist
```

As one of the primary ways of passing data into a template is using arrays, it seems like there should be some way of doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Twig is just a template engine. You know it right?

Comment: You can use "attribute" function: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

{% if  attribute(array, key) is defined %}
                       // do something
{% endif %}

Comment: @Vega You should add that as an answer, as it seems to be the only way to check for a key that isn't a single word, like `data-value`.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Twig example:

```
{% if array.key is defined %}
  // do something
{% else %}
  // do something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why can't we just use `{% if array.key %}`? What's wrong with it? In JS it's perfectly valid statement but not in Twig!

Comment: `{% if array.key %}` is valid, but it's the syntax to check if the array key is empty. [twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html#if](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html#if)

Comment: If key is a variable, you need to use `{% if array[ key ] %}` or `{% if array[ key ] is defined %}`. `array.key` tries to access index 'key' in the array.

Answer (score 42):

You can use the `keys` twig function

`{% if myVar in someOtherArray|keys %}`

Comment: This did the job for me, ty !

Comment: This is bad if used in a loop... There are much better answers, such using 'is defined'.. e.g. {% if someOtherArray[myVar] is defined %}

Comment: This works better in cases where the keys are not machine friendly. E.g. array['not-friendly']

Comment: If you are using dynamic key name, this answer is best.

Answer (score 4):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- DeveloperTLindel wants to test for existence of array key in Twig.
- DeveloperTLindel wants to trap any errors associated with undefined key.
- This can be handled using the `default` filter.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Twig 2.x (latest version as of Wed 2017-03-08)
- General-purpose use of the `default` filter.

#### Problem

- **Scenario:**
- DeveloperTLindel wants to test for existence of array key in Twig.
- DeveloperTLindel wants to avoid any errors or exceptions caused by potentially undefined key.

#### Solution

- DeveloperTLindel can use the `default` filter.
- The `default` filter catches any exceptions owing to undefined variable, and allows short-circuit substition of an alternate value.
- The `default` filter is chainable.

#### Example01

```
{#- ****************************************
  testing for a single key in associative array
  -#} 
  {%- set mystring = myarray['key-no-existo'] |default('__BLANK__')  -%}

{#- ****************************************
  testing for a multiple keys in associative array
  -#} 
  {%- set mystring = myarray['alpha']
        |default(myarray['bravo'])
        |default(myarray['charlie'])
        |default('__BLANK__')
        -%}
```

#### See also

- [SO: Similar question related to non-existent or null variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig)
- [SO: General purpose use of default filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896143/42223)

Answer (score 1):

SYMFONY 6

solution is quite simple TWIG is looking for variable passed when `$this->render` is called in Controller.

1. create your pack data like

   ```
                $options = [
                    'companyLogo' => $company->getCompanyLogoLink(),
                    'companyName' => $company->getCompanyShortname(),
                    'menuItem'    => $companyMenuCategories,

            ];
   ```
2. pass it to TWIG

   return $this->render('folder/template.html.twig', [
   'o' => $options,
   ]);
3. in twig just look for 'passed' key ( o ) and array data with it

   ```
      {% if o.companyName is defined %}
        {{ o.companyName }}
      {% endif %}
   ```