# How to display the code if there is a result?

Tags: if-statement, drupal, twig, drupal-8

How can I display this `{{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.0 }}` code if there is a result ?

Same suestion for this code `{{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.1 }}`

```
  <div class="mt-2">{{ content.field_ephemere_payment_method.0 }} à partir de {{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.0 }} jusqu'à {{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.1 }}</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607241/in-twig-check-if-a-specific-key-of-an-array-exists

Comment: Ok thanks i will test

Answer (score 0):

Having **Twig 1.12.0** ot later you may use null-coalescing operator:

```
<div class="mt-2">
    {{- content.field_ephemere_payment_method.0 ?? 'default value' }} à partir de {{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.0 ?? 'default value' }} jusqu'à {{ content.field_ephemere_payment_condition.1 ?? 'default value' -}}
</div>
```

Replace `default value` with any desired string, in case each of:

```
content.field_ephemere_payment_method.0
```

and

```
content.field_ephemere_payment_method.1
```

are not defined or are empty.