# How to check if a variable is equal to zero in twig and value defined

Tags: php, twig

This seems like a very basic question but I assure you I've run the gamut of solutions for this to work and I still haven't managed to find a solution.

The problem is this:

1. A twig value will be set with a value of 1, 0, or null by a select box and the value will then be used to set the selected value for that box.
2. There are two filters that are chosen - 1 for active, 0 for inactive.
3. If no value is set and the twig value is set empty (null) the option for 0 is always selected.

The twig code in question is as follows:

        `<option value="null">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="1"{% if filterStatus == 1 %} selected{% endif %}>Active</option>
        <option value="0"{% if filterStatus == 0  %} selected{% endif %}>Inactive</option>`

Is what I expected to use.  Below is one of many variations I attempted:

```
{% if filterStatus == 0 and not filterStatus != 'null' %}
```

I just can't seem to ensure the value is 0.

Also don't be fooled by the "null" value in the option value attribute.  This is used in routing, but translates to a literal NULL in the system and not a string by the time it makes it to twig.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for null in Twig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way of checking for not null is:

```
{% if var is not null %}
```

But you can use the `same as` function:

```
{% if var is same as(0) %}
    {# do something %}
{% endif %}
```

Ref: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
{% if filterStatus == 0 and filterStatus is (not) empty %}
```