# Impossible to access an attribute on a integer variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to access the value in twig from:

[image of data dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBYv7.png)

But keep getting an error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("startDate") on a integer variable ("2").

And in my twig it's:

```
{% for item in data %}

...

   {{ item.decoded.startDate }}

...
```

In Controller:

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
   $d->decoded = json_decode($d->getValue());
}
```

Can somebody help skipping the error when the value is **integer** or **null**?

Comment: Fix the error in the controller, don't use mixed value arrays. How to check for null is answered in several variations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I do not understand what do you mean by "mixed value arrays"? What should be fixed? @DanielW.

Comment: Yeah, maybe not all items have decoded.startDate. Perhaps implement that kind of check before trying to print the value.

Comment: It seems some `item.decoded` are an `object` containing date information and some contain just the `integer` `2`. That's mixed array values. Make them all contain an object or null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dump item.decoded to see if startDate is available

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).